# encontrar el digito mayor en un array de forma recursiva en C#

Tags: c#, recursión

Soy estudiante y estoy empezando en la programación, mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Tengo que crea una función que devuelva la cifra más alta que aparece en un número entero largo que recibio por parámetro, de manera iterativa y recursiva.

En su versión iterativa lo planteo descomponiendo ese numero largo en un array de digitos y luego voy comparando los numeros del array para asignar a una variable el numero mayor y la devuelvo en el return.

El problema es cunado lo intento plantear para hacerlo de forma recursiva, no tengo muy claro cual seria el caso base y mucho menos que poner en el return.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Pongo aqui el codigo:

```
class ObtenerMDigito_95
{
    static long ObtenerMayorDigito(long numeroLong)//Forma iterativa
    {
        string numeroString = Convert.ToString(numeroLong);
        long[] numeros = new long[numeroString.Length];
        long mayor = 0;

        for (int i = numeroString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            numeros[i] = numeroLong % 10;
            numeroLong /= 10;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= numeros.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (numeros[j] >= mayor)
            {
                mayor = numeros[j];
            }

        }
        return mayor;
    }
    static long ObtenerMayorDigitoR(long numeroLong)//Forma recursiva
    {
        string numeroString = Convert.ToString(numeroLong);
        long[] numeros = new long[numeroString.Length];
        long mayor = 0;

        for (int i = numeroString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            numeros[i] = numeroLong % 10;
            numeroLong /= 10;
        }

        if (numeros.Length == 2 && numeros[0] >= numeros[1])
        {
            mayor = numeros[0];
        }
        else
        {
            mayor = numeros[1];
        }
        return  mayor = ObtenerMayorDigitoR( numeroLong/10 ) ;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        long numero = 345;
        Console.WriteLine(ObtenerMayorDigito(numero));
        Console.WriteLine(ObtenerMayorDigitoR(numero));
    }
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo como texto

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento como texto y no como una imágen. Para editar tu pregunta has click aqui [edit] Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int MayorDigito(int num, int mayor = 0)
{
   int digito = num % 10;

   if (digito > mayor)
   {
      mayor = digito;
   }

   if (num < 10)
   {
      return mayor;
   }

   num = num / 10;

   return MayorDigito(num, mayor);
}
```

Esta función recibe dos parámetros, el número, y el dígito que va siendo el mayor hasta ese momento, dentro de la función se va obteniendo cada dígito del número a través de la operación:

```
int digito = num % 10;
```

Posteriormente comparamos si el dígito obtenido a partir de la operación anterior es mayor que el mayor dígito hasta ese momento, de cumplirse esta condición pues actualizamos el valor de la **variable mayor** con el valor de la **variable digito**.

Posteriormente verificamos el **paso base**:

```
if (num < 10)
{
    return mayor;
}
```

Esto quiere decir que si estamos en presencia del último dígito del número introducido simplemente devolvemos el valor que tiene la **variable mayor**, y a partir de este momento empezaremos a retornar a la función previamente llamada, hasta llegar a la invocación inicial de la función.

De no cumplirse el **paso base** pues le vamos quitando al número su última cifra a partir de la operación:

```
num = num / 10;
```

Y llamamos nuevamente a la función pasándole los parámetros correspondientes.

Para llamar a la función hacemos (Demostración en **Aplicación de Consola**):

```
Console.Write("Escriba un numero: ");

var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int mayor = Matematica.MayorDigito(num);

Console.WriteLine(mayor.ToString());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Le pedimos al usuario que escriba un número, y llamamos a la función:

```
int mayor = Matematica.MayorDigito(num);
```

Aunque la función en su declaración recibe dos parámetros aquí solamente le pasamos uno, ya que de no especificarse el segundo parámetro por defecto toma el valor de **0**, ya que en la declaración de la función:

```
public int MayorDigito(int num, int mayor = 0)
```

se pone en el segundo parámetro:

```
mayor = 0
```

Por último después de obtener el mayor dígito del número introducido, pues este dígito se imprime por consola.